# Exception in thread "main" acm.util.ErrorException: Cannot determine the main class.

Tags: java, linux

I started to learn both programming and Java and I have an issue I'm not able to solve on my own so far. I'm running the program from the Linux terminal using:

First `javac` to create the `.class` file

```
javac -classpath acm.jar Chap6_ex1.java
```

Want to add here that both the `acm.file` and the `Chap5_ex3.java` file are both at the same location as the terminal path.

Then I run this command

```
java -cp .:acm.jar Chap6_ex1
```

The output i get is :

```
Exception in thread "main" acm.util.ErrorException: Cannot determine the main class.
    at acm.program.Program.main(Program.java:1358)
```

I don't understand what's the problem, all my earlier programs worked with no issues.
I suspect the issue is caused by the fact that the `RandomGenerator` class is based on another class called `Random` from the `java.util` package but i don't know who to make the program work.

```
import acm.util.* ;
import java.util.*;
import acm.program.*;
import java.awt.* ;


class Chap6_ex1 extends ConsoleProgram {


    public void run() {

        println("This program displays a randomly schosen card.");      
        int number = rgen.nextInt(1 ,13);
        int suit = rgen.nextInt(1 ,4);
        cardNumber(number);
        print(" of ");
        suitNumber(suit);
    }
    private void cardNumber(int n){
        switch (n) {
            case 1 :
                println("Ace");
                break;
            case 11 : 
                println("Jack");
                break;
            case 12 :
                println("Queen");
                break;
            case 13:
                println("King");
                break;
            default :
                println(""+n);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void suitNumber (int n) {
        if(n == 1 ){
            print("Clubs");}
        else if (n ==2 ){
            print("Diamonds");}
        else if (n == 3){
            print("Hearts");}
        else {
            print("Spades");}
    }


    private RandomGenerator rgen = RandomGenerator.getInstance();

}
```

Comment: Is this your whole program ? If yes how it is supposed to start ? You are missing main method thats exactly what compiler is saying

Comment: I suggest you look at Program.java which contributed to acm.jar, wherever you got that...

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue , i forgot to put public at the start of the Class declaration .